# converting an object to HttpContent

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, httpresponse

While converting an object to HttpContent , compilation succeeds. But while running I am getting below error.

> ***Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies.***

My Code snippet:

```
 JArray jarray = (JArray)response;  //response is of type var.    
 IEnumerable<MyModelClass> appResponse = jarray.ToObject<IEnumerable<MyModelClass>>();    
 HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();    
 msg.Content = new ObjectContent<IEnumerable<ConfigurationResponseDomainModel>>(appResponse, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");
```

This line throws error. Assigning object to content. I am using Newtonsoft.Json(10.0.3). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Clean & rebuild help?

Comment: From stan: 
Does your project have different version of newton ?

Comment: Add a binding redirect to web.config. Better yet, add JSON.NET as a NuGet package. It will automatically add the redirects. The latest version is 11.0.2

Comment: BTW you could just search for that error message and find a lot of duplicate questions

Comment: BTW in ASP.NET MVC you could remove *all* of this code and simply use JSON.NET to serialize your actual objects to a string and return it with a StringContent. In Web API simply return your objects eg with `Ok()` or `Json()`, it uses JSON.NET already to serialize responses to JSON. .NET Core uses JSON.NET throughout